# Tridion 2013 SP1 Experience Manager Create New Page gets 404

Tags: 2013, experience-manager

i am getting 404 when creating new page on Tridion 2013 SP1 experience manager, when i check the publishing queue, the page is rendering... after the queue says published, i refresh the experience manager, the new page shows up. it looks like the experience manager Invoke gets the JSON data says isPublished="true", and try to load the page. however, the page is not rendered. is it a configuration issue or bug. any expert can help thanks.

attached browser network log, test102.aspx get 404, prevous Invoke gets JSON data says isPublished="true", and experience manager try to load test102.aspx, but the page still in rendering stange. hope this helps understanding the issue.

[image]

Comment: check this, if it helps http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-A484302D-31DA-474E-B70F-3A98773C38F7

Comment: thanks Raj, i did this step and it didn't help, experience manager try to load se_blank.html. any other suggestion... :)

Comment: Are you trying to edit page through XPM ?

Comment: I am trying to create a new page

Comment: You can take reference from below link to match your configs and binaries https://code.google.com/p/kickstart-tridion-environment/source/browse/#svn%2FCreateAnEnvironmentForMe%2FCreateAnEnvironmentForMe%2FConfigSamples%2Fpreview-webservice

Comment: Did you manage to find a resolution to this issue? We are having the exact same problem in both our development and production environments.

I am raising a SDL support ticket and will update with any feedback / help I can.

Answer (score 2):

We have been able to fix this on our system. We were checking the publication target type on render and only outputting the XPM code if equals staging `publicationTargetType == 'staging'`. By changing this logic to `publicationTargetType != 'live'`, creating a new page and update preview then all kicked in to action. We all learn from our mistakes.